# Technology for a reliable, persistent stack

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Trying a mental reset here: I tried to create a reliable, persistent stack with MSMQ, didn't work

So in more general terms:

I have producer (a webservice, so multithreaded although "only one") / consumer (multiple processes, as many as needed) setup. The key problems are
- The data needs to be consumed/processed in LIFO order (~> stack)
- The data needs to be stored/handled in a reliable way (i.e. backed by a disk, message queue, whatever). Bonus points for transaction support.
- Interprocess communication involved

Given the points above I struggle to find a neat solution. What I looked at:

1. Do it yourself
   Didn't really plan to do that, but initial proof of concepts for this just confirmed that this is hard (for me) and helped me get a better grasp on the many hurdles involved.
2. MSMQ
   Would be nice and easy, since it lends itself easily to "reliable", is easy to set up and already part of the target infrastructure. Unfortunately "LIFO"/"Stack" is a killer here. That seems to be impossible to do -> Bzzzt.
3. Database (SQL Server)
   I tried to look at a DB based approach, but there are lots of ugly things involved:

   - I'd need to store my data as a blob (since it doesn't lend itself to a column based store easily)
   - Polling a database for work just seems wrong (is it?)
   - Locking with multiple consumers seems to be tricky..

Any suggestion for a technology that I should evaluate? The database based approach seems to be the most "promising" so far, but I still haven't found good examples/success stories of similar usecases.

---

#### Updates

- Windows only
- For now, I don't even need to do inter-machine communication (i.e. producer/consumer probably *will* be on one machine for now)
- The key part in the question, the difficult task for me is: I cannot lose a job/message, even if all processes go down. A DB would give me that "for free", message queues can be set up to be reliable. Map/reduce, while interesting, isn't solving the core issue: How do I make sure that messages/jobs aren't lost?

Comment: Polling a database for work isn't necessarily wrong. It just won't scale well if your application grows too fast.

Comment: What platforms you want to support can be useful to know here.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I'm not going to rule out that solution at all: It's the best lead I have so far. I dislike the "blob in db" and "poll the db" thing, but I probably could live with that. Next issue is: Competing consumer processes fighting for jobs seems to be tricky without causing massive performance penalties or locking problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with SQL Server for this.

1. Obviously you'd have to serialize your data to a blob, but any solution would have to do this (at least behind the scenes). You would then just have a table like `CREATE TABLE Stack (Id int identity, Data varbinary(MAX))`
2. Polling the database isn't necessary. SQL Server has a query notification service where you just give it a query and it will notify you when the results would be different. Your notification query would just be `SELECT * FROM Stack`
3. Locking is the database's problem, not yours. You would just have every consumer run a query (or stored procedure) that uses a transaction to return the most recent entry (the row with the highest Id) and delete it at the same time. If the query returns a result, process it and run it again. If the query returns no results, see #2.

Here's a sample query:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT Data FROM Stack WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Stack)
DELETE FROM Stack WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Stack)
COMMIT
```

Here's a more elegant version that doesn't even require an explicit transaction:

```
DELETE Stack
OUTPUT DELETED.Data
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Stack)
```

If you want to do batch processing of 10 items at a time, you would use SQL like this:

```
DELETE Stack
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE Id IN (SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM Stack ORDER BY Id DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks! Lots of good pointers in here. Have to read up on the query notification service. The queries still bother me, but that might be due to my lack of deeper understanding.
The first example _seems_ to easily lead to race conditions/duplicates, if this would be code.
The second more directly says "this retrieval is atomic and removes the entry" to my untrained eyes, although I'm not sure about that subquery.
Since I want to process batches, I'd probably need to find a way to add a TOP xxx in there as well. Thanks a lot. Seems to be the most realistic option.

Comment: Argh. Okay, "Notification Services" sounded great, but unfortunately I learned about them through you, quite some time after they are still actively maintained. I'm working with MS SQL Server 2008 (a parallel 2005 installation is not an option) and it seems I'm out of luck there. So - polling it is..

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008, you want to use the "Service Broker" to deliver notifications (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166104.aspx), so you still don't have to worry about polling.

Comment: Accepted, since it's closest and I guess I have to start from here. The Service Broker seems to be useless though. It's a glorified message queue from what I can tell and - among other things - delivers messages in-order (fifo). Which is exactly what I cannot use.

Comment: All that the Service Broker does is deliver query notifications so you don't have to do polling. Since it doesn't actually give you the messages from your stack, it doesn't matter that it's implemented as a queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out AMQP. I'm digging around on google atm, and unfortunately have no reason to believe that it can maintain a stack instead of a queue, but there ARE several open source implementations and aside from the FIFO vs. LIFO issue it's a good fit for what you want.

I don't think the database table is a bad idea either, as long as you don't need to scale past a couple thousand transactions per second you should be just fine.

Comment: I've looked at some message queue implementations (although not AMQP, I've investigated zeromq/msmq so far) and they didn't seem to support my requirement: Every new message I post is automatically the single most important one. I'll try to look into some more alternatives on that front though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going down the DB route, you could look at Triggers.  It kind of depends on how sparse your messages are and how long you can wait to process them.

Comment: I'm sure there's a good idea behind this, I just lack the insight yet to see how triggers would help me. Basically a DB would, apart from the "store lots of blobs" smell, be difficult for me to use with competing consumers. I've seen quite some tricks for that, but a lot of those seemed quite hacky.
Do you know a more or less decent way to do that?

Comment: It's pretty much all ad-hoc.  The competing consumers problem can be solved with transactions.  I was suggesting that instead of polling, you could kick something off with an insert trigger. This would help if you expect messages to come far apart and need them to be serviced quickly when they arrive. If messages are arriving constantly, then polling isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

For point 3, you could look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) by the SO fanatic Jon Skeet, a means of serializing data to a binary blob that can easily be dumped....

In respect to Interprocess communication - what platform are we talking about here, if it's windows communicating with other windows machines, would a WCF not be suitable? As for transaction support - most ADO.NET has transaction support (as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978457.aspx) article), unless you are talking about a filesystem transactional support as per this [blog](http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/2007/12/07/SystemTransactionsAndWindowsVistaNTFSUpdated.aspx) entry, or even using the System.Transaction namespace as clarified [here](http://www.netframeworkdev.com/common-language-runtime/need-clarification--net-distibuted-transactions-34419.shtml) in respect to distributed transactions.

Comment: You packed some pretty nice things in that answer, but I don't think they help me. I already use System.Transactions/TransactionScopes in my application. Serialization with protobuf seems to be overkill: I don't want that. I receive xml snippets. I somehow have to process them, the processing is disconnected (not in the request handler..). For the pipe between producer and consumer I'm looking for a solution. The request handler needs to fire&forget and move on. The message _has_ to be processed afterwards, and needs to be stored safely in case the system/the processes shut down.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce sounds perfect for this and can be super scalable since it's what google uses for indexing web pages. Not sure what your preferable stack is but you may want to check out Hadoop

Comment: Thanks, I'm really interested in map/reduce and I do agree that this seems to be a nice fit for this application. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the reliability/persistence issue. It's completely orthogonal, as far as I can tell.
So while I might want to investigate M/R as a way to scale, I still need a way to push out xml fragments to <something> and _know_ that it's going to be processed, in a LIFO manner and hopefully in a somewhat sane way regarding efficiency/performance.